# When Scrooge recognizes a boy named "Toby Veck", is this a reference to someone?

Tags: reference, a-christmas-carol-1999

In the 1999 version of *A Christmas Carol* starring Patrick Stewart, Ebenezer Scrooge is traveling with the Ghost of Christmas Past and sees children he knew from his childhood.

At one point, Scrooge calls out "There's Toby Veck!" Is this a reference to someone? I checked the names of the writers and such, but didn't find anybody by that name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Toby Veck is the main character of another Dickens story, *The Chimes*, which is part of Dickens' series of Christmas Books, alongside *A Christmas Carol*.